# Hover video play only plays the last video in the DOM

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a component where each part has a little video. You hover over the video and it plays is the idea, however only the last video in the HTML actually plays.

Here is the typescript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", videoPlays, false);

function videoPlays() {
    var video: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName("video");

    for(var i = 0; i < video.length ; i++) {
        var vid: HTMLVideoElement = video[i] as HTMLVideoElement;

        vid.addEventListener("mouseover", (e :MouseEvent) => {
            vid.play();
        });

       vid.addEventListener("mouseout", (e :MouseEvent) => {
            vid.pause();
        });
    }
}
```

And the html is basically:

```
<video src="./images/rieky.mp4" class="video" loop></video>
<video src="./images/rieky.mp4" class="video" loop></video>
<video src="./images/rieky.mp4" class="video" loop></video>
<video src="./images/rieky.mp4" class="video" loop></video>
<video src="./images/rieky.mp4" class="video" loop></video>
```

Strongly assuming its something to do with all the items being the same in terms of their declaration, but I thought the DOM would differentiate by more than just their classname or whatever other properties it has.

Here is a gif of the issue in action. Notice the right hand side flexbox is the only video playing:

[image: Sorry the aspect is weird, got it under 2mb!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a issue but an behavior of variables declared with `var` statement, i.e. listeners will be attached to each video but they will call `play`/`pause` only for last video since the `var` is function-scoped and it holds only the reference to last item in the loop.
You can fix this by declaring the variables in the loop to be block-scoped with `let` statement, like so:

```
function videoPlays() {
    var video: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = document.getElementsByClassName("video");

    for(let i = 0; i < video.length ; i++) {
        let vid: HTMLVideoElement = video[i] as HTMLVideoElement;

        vid.addEventListener("mouseover", (e :MouseEvent) => {
            vid.play();
        });

       vid.addEventListener("mouseout", (e :MouseEvent) => {
            vid.pause();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Much appreciated :)